# How to set setContentHuggingPriority programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Im creating a view programmatically, but i can't set `setContentHuggingPriority` to work.
This is the current result:

[image: the red space should be equals the button]

```
private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    [button, text].forEach(stackView.addArrangedSubview)
    return stackView
}()

private lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(Asset.configIcon.image, for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    return button
}()

private lazy var text: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "This line should have more width than the button"
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    return label
}()
```

Comment: Your'e doing it right

Comment: so what i'm missing? @MojtabaHosseini

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the state that the button fits it's content and then the label takes any left space and fill it with multiline text.

Because you are using multiline label, You should set `contentCompressionResistancePriority` for both as well:

```
button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```